# jQuery prevent child records

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a nav that i need to add a `<br>` dynamically because the CMS we are using doesn't allow for this.

But it is affecting all of the child elements on the drop down.

Here is the basic HTML

```
<li class="dropdown yamm-fw" id="tab1"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Shop By Brand</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <ul class="col-sm-2 megaDropDown">
          <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
       </ul>
  </ul>
</li>
```

And here is the js that is adding the `<br>`

```
$(function(){
    $('#tab1 a').each(function( index ) {
        var aHtml = $(this).html();
        var pos = aHtml.lastIndexOf(' ');
        aHtml = aHtml.substring(0,pos) + '<br/>' + aHtml.substring(pos+1)
        $(this).html(aHtml);
    });
});
```

But i want it to affect tab1 a only nothing on the dropdown. I have a fiddle created here http://jsfiddle.net/6CTY8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`child selector`](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/).

From Docs:

```
Selects all direct child elements specified by "child" of elements specified 
by "parent".
```

Try this:

```
$('#tab1 > a').each(function( index ) {
        //YOUR CODE GOES HERE
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6CTY8/1/)**

Answer (score 3):

`$('#tab1 > a').each(function( index ) {`

Using `>` will make sure only direct descendants are used.

Here is a fiddle too.
http://jsfiddle.net/6CTY8/2/

Comment: excellent i will accept the answer as soon as SO will allow me to. Worked perfectly!